# complex conjugation of a signal

Tags: fourier-analysis

My textbook says:

> Taking the complex conjugate of a periodical signal x(t) has the
>   effect of complex conjugation and time reversal on the corresponding
>   Fourier series coefficients.

I understood the complex conjugation effect however I don't get why this operation also has the effect of time reversal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Fourier series coefficients

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x(t) e^{-itn}dt$$

we see that the coefficients of the conjugated signal are

$$c_n' = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^*(t) e^{-itn}dt =
\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x(t) e^{itn}dt\right\}^* = c_{-n}^*$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this means that $\widehat{\overline{x}}(m) = \overline{\widehat{x}(-m)}$. How to see this... Write $x(t) = y(t) + i z(t)$, where $y$ and $z$ are real-valued functions. The Fourier coefficients of $\overline{x}$ are
$$
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\overline{x}}(m) &= \int_0^1 \overline{x}(t) e^{-2\pi i t \cdot m} dt = \int_0^1 y(t) e^{-2\pi i t \cdot m} dt - i\int_0^1 z(t) e^{-2\pi i t \cdot m} dt\\
&= -\int_0^1 y(-t) e^{2\pi i t \cdot m} dt + i \int_0^1 z(-t) e^{2\pi i t \cdot m} dt\\
\end{align*}
$$
by the change of variables $t \to -t$. Also, notice that the Fourier coefficients $\widehat{x}(-m)$ are
$$
\begin{align*}
\widehat{x}(-m) &= \int_0^1 x(t) e^{- 2\pi i m \cdot t} dt = \int_0^1 y(t) e^{-2\pi i t \cdot m} dt + i\int_0^1 z(t) e^{-2\pi i t \cdot m} dt\\
&= -\int_0^1 y(-t) e^{2\pi i t \cdot m} dt - i \int_0^1 z(-t) e^{2\pi i t \cdot m} dt
\end{align*}
$$
which is the conjugate of the expression obtained above.